If every pair of generators generates an elementary group, is the group generated by all the generators necessarily elementary?
Let $G \leq SL(2, \mathbb{C})$. As discussed in Beardon's The Geometry of Discrete Groups (Exercise 5.1, Problem 2), $G$ is elementary (i.e., has a finite $G$-orbit in $\mathbb{R}^3$) if and only if for all $g, h \in G$, the two-generated group $\langle g, h\rangle$ is elementary.
I am curious if there is a similar characterization of finitely generated subgroups, but where one only needs to check elementary-ness on the generators. In particular, is the following claim true?
Claim: Let $G = \langle g_1, \dots, g_\ell \rangle \leq SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ be finitely generated. Then $G$ is elementary if and only if for all generators $g, h \in \{g_1, \dots, g_\ell\}$ the two-generated group $\langle g, h \rangle$ is elementary.
Obviously the "only if" direction holds, but what about the "if" direction?

No, this is false. To prove it, use the fact that any two involutions generate an elementary subgroup. As an example which does not use involutions, take 3 distinct points $x, y, z\in S^2$ and 3 nontrivial Moebius transformations $f, g, h$, fixing, respectively, $\{x,y\}, \{y, z\}, \{z, x\}$. Then they generate a nonelementary subgroup but each pair of generators fixes a point from $\{x, y, z\}$.

I see, thanks! As a follow-up, what if I replace the condition "elementary" with "discrete"? Like elementary, it's true that a non-elementary $G$ is discrete if and only if for all $g, h \in G$ the two-generated subgroup $\langle g,h\rangle$ is discrete. If $G = \langle g_1, \dots, g_\ell \rangle$ is finitely generated and not elementary, is it the case that $G$ is discrete if and only if for all $g,h \in {g_1, \dots, g_\ell}$ the two-generated subgroup $\langle g, h\rangle$ is discrete? If so, you could test the discreteness of finitely generated $G$ by appealing to Jorgensen's inequality.

@trillianhaze: This would be false as well, you can even have finite subgroups generated by such pairs.

@trillianhaze To find such an example, observe that there are arbitrarily small triangles $T$ in the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb H^2$ with angles that are rational multiples of $\pi$. The hyperbolic isometry group $G$ generated by reflections in the edges of $T$ is nondiscrete if $T$ is small enough (by Margulis Lemma or Jorgensen inequality, if you prefer). At the same time, any two generators of $G$ generate a finite group of isometries. This example is orientation-reversing, but it extends to a group of isometries of $\mathbb H^3$ which preserves orientation. There are other examples too.

Great, thank you!
